# My App On Play Store But get some warning related to reCaptcha , i am not add any library related to captcha

Tags: recaptcha

[Here is my error Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuKOS.png)

please help me anyone guys, I am not use any reCaptcha Library in my project, then why  detect play store console on my sdk, if anyone know about that please resolve my problem. Your help most welcome to me thanks, please review this.